# UEFI / Legacy issue in Boot

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, uefi

I downloaded Linux Mint v19 and successfully installed through legacy boot (why I did it it through legacy, I'll explain later).

However, turning on the computer only boots straight into Windows, even though I had moved, switched and set everything I could to enable GRUD.

I think it's because I'm booting into legacy mode, however as Windows is installed into legacy mode, I can't switch that configuration because it only displays a black screen with a "No OS found" message, no matter if I install Linux as legacy or UEFI.

Formatting the hard drive as UEFI is not an option. But I've tried everything else, and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Try Boot Repair from the installation media: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair . If that doesn't work, you may need to manually edit the boot options on the HDD, e.g. replacing the Windows.efi file with grub.efi (or similar filenames).

Comment: Ok I made Boot Repair, 'tough  I was a bit scared got myself a linux live usb and booted it.

Comment: Now Linux is Working :) However I messed up Windows and now I can't boot it

Answer (score 1):

OK, I solved it. For whoever is reading this and may need help, this is what I did:

After installing Linux and rebooting, I couldn't access to it, but was able to just boot straight into Windows. I read that I needed to have Linux installed on the same boot type as Windows, so I installed it again through USB in legacy mode which is my Boot type. (You can check your's through "msinfo32" on your Windows task prompt).

It didn't work, because it didn't showed GRUB (the menu that allows to switch between OS), but I finally had my two OS on the same Boot Type, so I knew it was possible.

I used the same Linux USB I used to install it in first place and booted into live mode, and then installed Boot Repair using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

Set up "Boot Repair" and then restarted. I tried to access Windows, and it only displayed a bugged black screen which scared me a lot. But I kept myself together, and tried to boot again into Linux Mode. It worked perfectly.

There, into the actual Linux installation I had made many hours ago, I started thinking of re-installing Windows, until I came across the possibility of reinstalling "Boot Repair". I was working in a real Linux environment, running into my actual hard drive and not a USB live boot; so there was a chance it could work.

Reinstalled "Boot Repair", restarted my PC, selected Windows 10 (which oddly showed as Windows 8 the time it didn't boot) and it started as usual.

After hours of work, I finally came across a functional Windows/Linux dual boot with my own style. So don't give up!

Maybe this post or the similar hundreds on the Internet may help you as well as it did for me, taking a little from each post.